# How to check if the files I upload have the same file names with the ones I already have?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am developing a file browser using react.js. My idea is to compare the file.name and file.size(which should be the name and size of the file I intend to upload) to every single file's name and size that I already have on the browser (which are stored in a useState variable named 'files'). If the name matches to any existing file's, while the size does not, I will call the '/createversion' endpoint, if both name and size match, I will not do anything, and if none matches, I will just append the file into the formdata and call the '/createdocument' endpoint to create the files on the file browser:

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([])

  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {

    const formData = new FormData()

    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].name === file.name && files[i].size !== file.size) {
          formAPI().post('/createversion/' + files[i].id, config)
          console.log(files[i])
          console.log(files[i].name)
        }
      else {
        formData.append(file.name, file)
        console.log(formData)
      }
    }})
    const config = {
      headers: {
        // Authorization: `Bearer ${userContext.userInfo.token}`
      }
    }

    formAPI().post('/createdocument', formData, config)
      .then(res => {
        updateFilesHandler()
        Notification(`${acceptedFiles.length > 0 ? 'files' : 'file'} successfully uploaded`)
      }).catch(err => {
        authErrorHandler(err, userContext.logoutHandler, history)
      })

  }, [])
```

I know the way how I check the file properties is completely wrong. And the following way does not work either. Somehow the arrow function throws an error.

```
const filteredArray = array1.filter(value => array2.includes(value));
```

I tried all I could basically, what would be a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: What are the symptoms of the problem? What's the error?

Comment: no /createversion/ request made. I think that has something to do with the way I check the file